# Rails Specialized Model Instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, model

First - alternate suggestions are welcome as the design is flexible.

Say we have a Badges database (think gamification). There are certain Badge instances that are expected to exist in the database (attributes: name, description, image). I'd like to define specialized methods (earned()) that test whether a user qualifies for a badge whose behaviour depends on particular *instances* of the model.

Basically, the id of the badge determines they behavior of the earned() function.

Is there a standard way to do this? It's got a hint of design smell to me.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do? What kinds of behaviors are changing depending on the badge ID?

Comment: The earned() function. In one case it might count the number of times you've logged in. In another, it might count the points you've earned in the past 4 weeks. In another, it might calculate your point earning rate and award you for 4 weeks of linear increases.